# How to disable Mail Drop in iOS 9.2?

Tags: ios, email, mail-drop

Prior to iOS 9.2, large videos would be resized when sending as an e-mail attachment. After 9.2 introduced Mail Drop however, this resizing functionality seems to be disabled even if I opt not to use Mail Drop.

The recipients I'm sending the video to have very limited bandwidth (3G cellular) and I do not wish to send them the full sized video - even if they could figure out how to open files from Mail Drop (which they can't)

Is there a way to completely disable Mail Drop on iOS like there is in OS X to get this resizing behavior back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still compress a video and bypass Mail Drop when you compose a new email and manually attach the video (by long clicking email body).